# copying multiple tomcat files using a batch without overwriting same names

Tags: batch-file, tomcat

we just had a change to our multiple tomcat servers. the logs used to be 
tomcat8-stdout.%logdate%.log

and i was able to use multiple COPY commands in my batch and if the filename was identical, i would append an (x) to them

```
Copy Z:\logs\TOMCAT6\tomcat8-stdout.%logdate%.log %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tomcat_log\tomcat8-stdout.%logdate%(6).log
```

you know, like windows does almost automagically

NOW, they have the logs in multiple folders, all by date, meaning i can't just jump in can grab them using a %logdate% variable, and the folders do not match %logdate% either

so I am using the following stolen code from stackoverflow

```
set dSource="X:"
set dTarget=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tomcat_log\
set fType=*stdout.%logdate%.log
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (
    copy /V "%%f" "%dTarget%\" 2>nul
)
```

but i think it is overwriting log files with the same filename, how do i fix this?

my end goal is that we have tomcat logs all in subfolders for multiple servers and I just want to get logs for a specific date to a temp folder for use